# Json string not formatted in browser but formatted in console

Tags: java, spring, jackson

I am trying to output object serialized to json like this

```
@GetMapping("/person")
public String getPerson() throws JsonProcessingException {
    mapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
    System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(person)); //just for debug
    return mapper.writeValueAsString(person);
}
```

I get what I wish in console:

```
{
  "name" : "person",
  "age" : 29,
  "listSkills" : [ "s1", "s2", "s3" ],
  "id" : 1,
  "hashCode" : 2145420209
}
```

but in browser it is printed in one line and just gets different font

{ "name" : "person", "age" : 29, "listSkills" : [ "s1", "s2", "s3" ], "id" : 1, "hashCode" : 2145420209 }

Comment: Is your browser output the text that you see in the "view source" mode? Or the rendered version?

Comment: but writeValueAsAStringReturns String - i returned a Person previously but then I decided to make it look pretty in browser and got into this solution. I tried in Chrome and Safari - same result.

Comment: You should not format `JSON` on the server side. You increase the response size and waste a time. Format it on the frontend side if needed but I believe it is not.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problems

1. You expect browser to have the same font(and colors) as console!? (Your expectations "base on wrong assumptions"/you must care)
2. You don't use `@[Rest]Controller` as [intended/documented](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/web.html#mvc-ann-return-types).
3. Obviously `ResponseBody<String>` (which you in fact return) doesn't behave as expected regarding white space.

#### Solution

1. [Spring-boot-starter-web](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=2.6.2&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=web) [x]
2. application.properties:

   ```properties
   spring.jackson.serialization.indent_output=true
   ```
3. Impl:

   - Person:

     ```java
     package com.example.webtest;
     import java.time.LocalDate;

     public class Person {
        private String name;
        private LocalDate date;
        // default constructor (implicit)
        // getters, setters:
        public String getName() {
          return name;
        }
        public Person setName(String name) {
          this.name = name;
          return this; // fluent api (not mandatory...)
        }
        public LocalDate getDate() {
          return date;
        }
        public Person setDate(LocalDate date) {
          this.date = date;
          return this;
        }
     }
     ```
   - Application + Controller:

     ```java
     package com.example.webtest;

     import java.time.LocalDate;
     import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
     import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
     import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
     import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

     @SpringBootApplication
     public class WebTestApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
          SpringApplication.run(WebTestApplication.class, args);
        }

        @RestController
        static class SomeController {

          @GetMapping("/hello")
          public Person hello() { // Person! not String ;)
            return new Person().setName("Joe").setDate(LocalDate.now());
          }
        }
     }
     ```
4. Test (spring-boot:run,..browser) at `http://localhost:8080/hello`:

   [image]

#### Key points

- Using spring-boot "jacksonObjectMapper" (auto & properties config).
- Returning the desired type and *not a String*.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a json formatter for your browser e.g. for Chrome this one is quite popular: [JSON Formatter](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/json-formatter/bcjindcccaagfpapjjmafapmmgkkhgoa?hl=en) or you can find a similar one for your browser of choice.

Usually they come with great features such as sintax highlighting, clickable urls, toggles and some more.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring boot, the GET method will produce result with content type of `application/json` by default.

If you want a formatted string in browsers, set produces to `text/plain`, aka

```
@GetMapping(value = "/person", produces = MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE)
```